# How would I check the version of a program using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that needs to check the version of the program it works with. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but right now I have a psuedo-loop that checks to see if the path exists to the the latest version from .8 - .0. Assuming that the proper path to the program is C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.6, I would hope that the variable ver would store the value I need. Why doesn't this code work, or is there a better way to do what I need?

```
set ver=8
:CheckVer
if EXISTS C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.%ver% GOTO NextStep
ver=ver-1
if ver LSS 0 GOTO NotFound
GOTO CheckVer
```

The solution for me as outlined in the comments was this:

```
set /a ver=8
:CheckVer
if EXIST C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.%ver% GOTO NextStep
set /a ver=%ver%-1
if %ver% LSS 0 GOTO NotFound
GOTO CheckVer
```

Comment: This is not a valid command. `ver=ver-1`.  You need to use `SET /A` to do math operations. You are also not referencing the variable correctly in your second if command. You are missing the percent symbols for the `ver` variable. `if %ver% LSS 0 GOTO NotFound`

Comment: I patched it up, and everything works except the EXISTS line. Not sure whats preventing it from running. Am I not able to append the variable ver to the end of the path?
`SET /A ver = 8
:CheckVer
if EXISTS C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.%v% GOTO NextStep
SET /A ver = %ver% - 1
IF %ver% LSS 0 GOTO NotFound
GOTO CheckVer`

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `if /?`, read the information, then fix the command to use the  syntax shown within it, i.e. `EXIST` not `EXISTS`! Please note also that is is unlikely that you will have an executable program named `5.0`, `5.1`, `5.2`, `5.3`, `5.4`, `5.5`, `5.6`, `5.7`, or `5.8`, on Windows they almost always are named `something.exe`!

Comment: Also note that I did not say anything about using percent symbols with your variable names when using `SET /A`.  Using `SET /A ver=ver - 1` would have been acceptable as well as `SET /A ver-=1`.

Comment: @Compo That worked, thank you! And I'm not looking for the executable, as they all have the same name. The path was just the easiest way to identify the version of the program.

Comment: Well if you're wanting to check the name of a directory instead, _which seems like what you're doing based upon your latest comment_, then you should be using a trailing backslash, to differentiate it from a file name, `If Not Exist "C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.%ver%\" GoTo NextStep`. And for the purpose of your code above, why not just use one line, instead of those six, `Dir /B/AD "C:\Apps\ProgramName" 2>NUL|FindStr /X "5\.[0-8]">NUL||GoTo NextStep`. Or the more correct, `Dir /B /A:D "C:\Apps\ProgramName" 2>NUL | "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /R /X "5\.[012345678]" >NUL || GoTo NextStep`.

Comment: Why not simply using `for /D %%I in ("C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.*") do set "ProgramVersion=%%~nxI" & echo Found ProgramName in version %%~nxI`? Or if it is possible to have multiple folders matching wildcard pattern `5.*`, use `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Apps\ProgramName\5.*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do set "ProgramVersion=%%I"` and write on next line `echo Found ProgramName in version %ProgramVersion%`. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help, next run `dir /?` and read the output help.

Answer (score 0):

```
REM FileVer.bat
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"
```

To use

```
c:\folder\filever.bat c:\windows\notepad.exe
```